# Validate string parameter length and special character

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to validate a string parameter is at least 8 characters, maximum length 32 and contains at least one special character. This is what I have so far:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[ValidateLength(8, 32)]
[ValidateScript({ $_ -match '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' })]
[string]$Param1
```

I'm not sure if the regex is correct? My testing has shown varying results.

Comment: It depends how you define a special char, `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` matches any char other than ASCII letters ad digits.

Comment: You _might_ want to list the special characters instead of a negative character class.  Otherwise you could end up with some strange unicode or emjoi as the special character, but maybe you'd want that?

Comment: Showing some inputs and expected results would be helpful.

Comment: Try `^(?=.*[special characters]).{8,32}$`

Comment: Are you validating a password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
{
[ValidateScript(
{
    $_ -match "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$@!%&])[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&]{8,32}$"
})]
}
```

That will match on 8 to 32 characters, has at least 1 upper case, 1 lowercase, one number, and a special character

Comment: Cite from `Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators` By default, all comparison operators are case-insensitive. To make a 
    comparison operator case-sensitive, precede the operator name with a "c".